# Простая задача Python

Tags: python

есть такая задача:

1. Напишите программу, которая будет принимать числа от пользователя и суммировать их, пока он не напишет слово «sum».
2. Когда пользователь напишет слово «sum», должна быть выведена сумма всех чисел и начат процесс заново.
3. Если пользователь напишет «exit» или «quit», программа должна быть завершена.

нашел решение через гугл. вроде не сложная задача но есть непонятные моменты для меня можете разъяснить в виде комментариев к строчкам кода(что понимаю сам от комментил). Правильно ли я выставил комментарии?

```
sum1 = 0                                                                # Задаем значение переменной sum1
while True:                                                             # Начало цикла
    value = input('Введите число: ')                                    # Создаем переменную value которая просит ввести число
    if value == "sum":                                                  # Если ввести слово sum то он
        print("Общая сумма: ", sum1)                                    # выведет  общую сумму введенных значений
        sum1 = 0
        continue                                                        # Переход в начало цикла
    elif value == "exit" or value == "quit":
        break
    sum1 += int(value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Правильно ли я выставил комментарии?

Да, ваши комментарии сделаны вами верно.
Также я бы вам сделал некоторое дополнение:

1. Я бы не рекомендовал писать 'while True:', так как в более сложных кодах, где конструкция будет запутанней, лучше использовать 'флаг', то есть делать проверку на положении флага.
   Например:

```
sum1 = 0                                                                # Задаем значение переменной sum1
flag = True
while flag:                                                             # Начало цикла
    value = input('Введите число: ')                                    # Создаем переменную value которая просит ввести число
    if value == "sum":                                                  # Если ввести слово sum то он
        print("Общая сумма: ", sum1)                                    # выведет  общую сумму введенных значений
        sum1 = 0
        continue                                                        # Переход в начало цикла
    elif value == "exit" or value == "quit":
        flag = False
    if flag:
        sum1 += int(value)
```

На данном примере может не очень видна разница, но, если у вас будут вложенные циклы, то с  'флагом' будет удобнее и понятней.

Comment: В данной задаче введение флага только усложняет/удлиняет код. А так то случаи, конечно, бывают разные.

Answer (score 0):

```
summa = 0
while True:
    o = input()
    if o.isdigit():
        summa += int(o)
    if o == 'exit' or o == 'quit':
        break
    elif o == 'sum':
        print(summa)
        summa = 0
```

Я Вам помог??

Comment: Вообще-то вопрос звучал так: "Правильно ли я выставил комментарии?" Так что помощи тут не много.  А так чуток код подрихтовали.  Но если уж что-то оптимизировали, то вместо "if o == 'exit' or o == 'quit':" надо было ставить "elif o == 'exit' or o == 'quit'".  Или после  summa += int(o) ставить continue.  Тогда бы хоть скорость выполнения малость сократили.